# are diabetes and obesity diseases?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Normally, I feel an illness is called a disease if it is caused by infection, and an infection is caused by **bacteria or a virus**.

But [the dictionary says](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/disease?q=disease)

> an illness affecting humans, animals or plants, often caused by infection
> ...
> **chronic** diseases such as obesity and diabetes

However, obesity and diabetes are not caused by by **bacteria or a virus**.

So any health condition can be called "**a disease**"?

Comment: Your idea that an illness is only called a 'disease' if it is caused by an infection is a mistake. The dictionary is right.

Comment: Illnesses caused, and spread by, infection are often called _infectious diseases_. A big part of the history of medicine in the last 100-150 years is the conquest of many of these.

Comment: There's a degree of "awkwardness" in this area, because [some people](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/NEyk-xuSYB4) think obesity is a *[consequence of] **lifestyle choice.*** I don't think lifelong conditions like spina bifida and multiple sclerosis (MS) are caused by infection, but do we really want to distinguish people disabled / handicapped by those conditions from others with actual *infections* (people damaged by polio, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - tricky territory these days, but once, as a young man in a new job, I saw that one of the staff was the most enormous person I had ever seen. A female colleague whispered 'it's his glands' in my ear. It was 1975.

Comment: The US [National Cancer Institute](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/understanding/what-is-cancer) calls cancer a "disease", the [WHO](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/diabetes) calls diabetes a "disease", and someone could check other examples of conditions not (usually) caused by infections.

Comment: @StuartF - there are plenty of diseases that are inherited, or caused by environmental factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary says '*often* caused by an infection'.

Oxford Languages (found by Googling *disease definition*) says *a disorder of structure or function in a human, animal, or plant, especially one that has a known cause and a distinctive group of symptoms, signs, or anatomical changes.*

As to whether obesity is one, see [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6179496/).